xpath selection of <p><a></a></p> but not <p>sometext<a>link</a>or some text</p>
so I need to inject an 'inlineAssetLink' class into an anchor tag that is part of a paragraph, but a class of 'blockAssetLink' into an anchor tag that is inside an otherwise empty paragraph.
Not sure this is even possible with xpath, but the content comes from a WYSIWYG editor in cms and I'd like to do this server-side rather than with javascript.
Already using DOMXPath to manipulate other parts of content so it would be nice to do the same for this.

Here's code that will load this into DOMDocument and will apply those classes to all anchors, by checking count of children of parent of each.
function addClassesToAnchors($html)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(
        "<div class='my-wrapper'>$html</div>",
        LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD
    );

    // get all anchors
    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
        $parentNode = $anchor->parentNode;

        if ($parentNode->nodeName == 'p') {
            $childNodes = $parentNode->childNodes;

            // count children, expect 1 for empty p
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($childNodes as $childNode) {
                $count++;
            }

            if ($count == 1) {
                $anchor->setAttribute('class', 'blockAssetLink');
            }
            if ($count > 1) {
                $anchor->setAttribute('class', 'inlineAssetLink');
            }
        }
    }

    // Get the content as HTML without the <div> wrapper
    $divElement = $dom->documentElement;
    $result = '';
    foreach ($divElement->childNodes as $node) {
        $result .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
    }

    return $result;
}

$html = "<p><a></a></p> <p>but not</p> <p>sometext<a>link</a>or some text</p>";
echo addClassesToAnchors($html);



FYI: No real need for the loop to count the children - childNodes is a DOMNodeList, and that implements the Countable interface - so you can just do count($parentNode->childNodes) directly.

@CBroe I tried but it gives 1 when it should 3 for some reason.

Can't see how that would make any sense (I doubt that Countable is implemented in a faulty way for DOMNodeList, people would have noticed by now), guess you must have made some mistake. But either way, if the code as shown helps solve OP's problem, this minor detail regarding implementation probably doesn't make much of a difference, I doubt the amount of nodes is so large, that looping would affect performance.

Maybe it's a matter for a new question. Because I double checked

See here it was fixed in PHP >= 7.2
